# How to make Qlistwidgetitems checked automatically if same items are in the specified list?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlistwidgetitem

Below is the example code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(394, 356)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 241, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 250, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 394, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        players = ["Player 1","Player 2","Player 3","Player 4"]

        for i in players:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(i)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        self.selected_list = ["Player 1", "Player 4"]

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.find_the_list)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def find_the_list(self):
        print("OKAY")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The `players = ["Player 1","Player 2","Player 3","Player 4"]` list has been added in to the QListWidgetItem as UserCheckable. And the second list `self.selected_list = ["Player 1", "Player 4"]` is have tow items and the second list is changeable. Now I want to check the boxes of QlistWidgetitems if the second list have the matched items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def find_the_list(self):
    for i in range(self.listWidget.count()):
        item = self.listWidget.item(i)
        if item.text() in self.selected_list:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```